# Free Play account and using AdMob in apps

Tags: android, admob

I am from a region where I cannot open Google merchant account but I have a free Play account means I cannot publish paid apps. I want to ask, can I earn money if I publish free apps with ads in it, like using AdMob.

Comment: yes, you can. Download the admob sdk and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can!

Instructions, tutorials and more information at http://www.google.com/ads/admob/